# компилятор пишет что не найден epoll_create1

Tags: android, c, sdl2

пишу сетевую игру для android на си + sdl2. вот `epoll_create1' есть в исходниках и вот что там написано.

```
#if __ANDROID_API__ >= 21
int epoll_create1(int __flags) __INTRODUCED_IN(21);
#endif /* __ANDROID_API__ >= 21 */
```

я только что подумал что может надо в `Android.mk` добавить флаг `-D__ANDROID_API__=21`. щас попробую. а так странно. я выставил в `Application.mk` минимальную версию `android-21` и думал что заработает.

Comment: да, сработало. только вроде теперь другие ошибки повалили.

Comment: ndk-build уже устарел